# In Treeline, how do I check if the current user is logged in?

Tags: sails.js, treeline

Using Treeline, how do I check if the current user is logged in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to implement a login system in Treeline.  Assuming you're going with a session-based system, you can use the **Remember** machine from the **Session** machinepack to save the user ID in a session variable (e.g. `userId`), and in a different route use the **Does Session Value Exist?** machine to check whether `userId` is set in the session.

You can also retrieve the user ID in any machine by inserting a session "bubble" in an input!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [Authentication Machinepack](http://node-machine.org/machinepack-sessionauth), which essentially does what Scott describes.